# How to solve Google CloudSQL 8 hours timeout?

Tags: hibernate, google-app-engine, entitymanager, google-cloud-sql, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm working in an app with Google Cloud SQL. I'm using Hibernate 4.2.0.Final and I've noticed that after 8 hours of inactivity my connection is closed. I've been searching on the Internet and I couldn't find anything effective to solve this issue. All the information I've found is summarized in these items:

- Use a connection pool where I should specify a higher timeout. I've tried with c3p0 and DBCP 2.1.1 libraries but none of them solved the issue.
- Open a connection before some query and then close it after that. The problem is that I would like to use the EntityManager in order to use queries with entities.

Here it's what I've done with DBCP 2.1.1 (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2/2.1.1). The problem is that Goggle App Engine logs show an `ExceptionInInitializerError` when I try to use `findAll` in my `PersistenceService`. The logs also show that my `DataSource` (see below) cannot be cast to `String`. I don't understand why.

This is the `PersistenceService` I'm using right now

```
package co.peewah.ems.utils;

import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AvailableSettings;


/**
 *
 * @author Muacito
 */
public class PersistenceService
{
    private static final EntityManagerFactory EMF = createEntityManagerFactory();

    private static EntityManager entityManager = EMF.createEntityManager();

    private static EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory()
    {
        //String mode = "";
        /*
        if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Development)
        {
            mode = "dev.";
        }
        */

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        //Properties properties = new Properties();

        //properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", System.getProperty("persistence." + mode + "db.driver"));
        //properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getProperty("persistence." + mode + "db.url"));
        //properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", System.getProperty("persistence." + mode + "db.user"));
        //properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", System.getProperty("persistence." + mode + "db.password"));
        try
        {
            properties.put(AvailableSettings.DATASOURCE, DataSource.getInstance());
        } catch (IOException | SQLException | PropertyVetoException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println(properties);
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");

        return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Demo", properties);
    }

    private static EntityManager getEntityManager()
    {
        if (!PersistenceService.entityManager.isOpen())
        {
            PersistenceService.entityManager = PersistenceService.EMF.createEntityManager();
        }

        return PersistenceService.entityManager;
    }

    public static <T> void create(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity.getClass().getMethod("getId").invoke(entity) == null)
            {
                entity.getClass().getMethod("setId", String.class).invoke(entity,
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", ""));
            }

            if (entity.getClass().getMethod("getCreated").invoke(entity) == null)
            {
                entity.getClass().getMethod("setCreated", Date.class).invoke(entity,
                        GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime());
            }

            getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();

            getEntityManager().persist(entity);

            getEntityManager().flush();

            getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(PersistenceService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

    public static <T> void edit(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            if (entity.getClass().getMethod("getUpdated").invoke(entity) == null)
            {
                entity.getClass().getMethod("setUpdated", Date.class).invoke(entity,
                        GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime());
            }

            getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();

            getEntityManager().merge(entity);

            getEntityManager().flush();

            getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(PersistenceService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

    public static <T> void remove(T entity)
    {
        try
        {
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();

            getEntityManager().remove(entity);

            getEntityManager().flush();

            getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(PersistenceService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            getEntityManager().getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

    public static <T> List<T> filter(Class<T> entityClass, String query, SimpleEntry<String, Object>... parameters)
    {
        TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(query, entityClass);

        for (SimpleEntry<String, Object> param : parameters)
        {
            typedQuery.setParameter(param.getKey(), param.getValue());
        }

        return typedQuery.getResultList();
    }

    public static <T> T find(Class<T> entityClass, Object id)
    {
        T entity = getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);

        return entity;
    }

    public static <T> List<T> findBy(Class<T> entityClass, String criteria, Object value)
    {
        String c = criteria.replaceFirst(criteria.charAt(0) + "", (criteria.charAt(0) + "").toLowerCase());

        TypedQuery<T> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(entityClass.getSimpleName() + ".findBy" + criteria,
                entityClass);
        query.setParameter(c, value);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public static <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> entityClass)
    {
        CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));

        return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    }

    public static <T> List<T> findRange(Class<T> entityClass, int[] range)
    {
        CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
        q.setMaxResults(range[1] - range[0] + 1);
        q.setFirstResult(range[0]);

        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public static <T> int count(Class<T> entityClass)
    {
        CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        Root<T> rt = cq.from(entityClass);
        cq.select(getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);

        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    }
}
```

This is my `DataSource`

```
package co.peewah.ems.utils;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;

import com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty;

/**
 *
 * @author csacanam
 *
 */
public class DataSource
{

    private static DataSource datasource;
    private BasicDataSource ds;

    private DataSource() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException
    {
        ds = new BasicDataSource();


        String mode = "";

        if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Development)
        {
            mode = "dev.";
        }

        String user = System.getProperty("persistence." + mode + "db.user");
        String password = System.getProperty("persistence." + mode + "db.password");
        String address = System.getProperty("persistence." + mode + "db.url");
        String driver = System.getProperty("persistence." + mode + "db.driver");

        // Create and configure DBCP DataSource
        ds.setDriverClassName(driver);
        ds.setUrl(address);
        ds.setUsername(user);
        ds.setPassword(password);

        ds.setMinIdle(5);
        ds.setMaxIdle(20);

        ds.setMaxOpenPreparedStatements(180);
    }

    public static DataSource getInstance() throws IOException, SQLException, PropertyVetoException
    {
        if(datasource == null)
        {
            datasource = new DataSource();    
        }

        return datasource;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException
    {
        return this.ds.getConnection();
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `autoReconnect=true` option for mysql connection. Most simple way is to add it to connection url itself:

```
persistence.db.url=jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/y?autoReconnect=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The 8 hour idle connection timeout comes from the mysql server, not the client, so changing timeouts on the client won't do much. This setting can be adjusted on the server by changing the `wait_timeout` flag. 8 hours is the default value.

You should configure your connection pool to automatically remove idle connections after some time. In DBCP you can enable the idle connection evictor via the `timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis` option.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit to the answer of Vadim, on CloudSQL you can set flags through the cloud console Edit instance. On Google you cannot do this by running something like `SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=60;` because it does not support SUPER privileges.

It took me a while to find this one out, so I figured it might help some else to add it here.