# Is there a way to simulate a MySQL database timeout in Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I'm currently developing a Google Cloud Run web application that hits MySQL and I've run into an error that I've been unable to replicate. I first ran into this issue after refreshing the app in the morning after leaving it open overnight.

Here's the error message:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 236,899,325 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 236,899,326 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

I understand that the cause of this problem is most likely due to the database connection timing out before my app does as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422632/jdbc-connection-timeout-cannot-reconnect).

I intend to add a flag increasing wait time by editing the Cloud MySQL instance as described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980375/how-to-solve-google-cloudsql-8-hours-timeout) to hopefully solve the issue.

I would like to replicate this problem so I can evaluate whether my intended solution will work in the future, but I haven't found a good answer for replicating a similar timeout.

In Google Cloud Platform, I've tried stopping and restarting the databases with which my app communicates but this didn't recreate the error.

Has anyone ran into a similar issue? If so, how would I go about recreating the error without having to wait overnight?

Comment: Why do you want such a long timeout? TCP connections can fail and do fail so you should design for failure and automatically reconnect. Cloud Run is an HTTP Request/Response system. Open connections and then close them for each HTTP request. Do not use or rely upon caching connections between requests.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a retry system instead of trying to replicate the connectivity issue. I would go trying to implement exponential backoff in my application as a first approach to do this.

The issue with trying to replicate the error, is that you may not be able to get exactly this error again as it may have been due to a factor that you have no control into.

I hope you find this information useful.